# Float comparison in awk and mawk

Tags: awk, mawk

I cannot understand why the float number comparison does not work in mawk:

```
mawk '$3 > 10' file.txt
[...]
9_6_F-repl      24834   38.8699
9_6_F   56523   17.9344
9_7_F   3196    3.68367
9_9_F   2278    2.37445
9_annua_M-merg  122663  163.557
9_huetii_F-merg 208077  172.775
[...]
```

While it does perfectly on awk like that:

```
awk '{if ($3 > 10) print $1}' file.txt
```

I'm obviously doing something wrong here, but I cannot understand what.

Comment: both code are not realy the same, even if they should do the same (test is at pattern level for the first and inside the action for a pattern matched in the second). do you try the awk version with mawk ?

Comment: I tried mawk version of the last command: `mawk '{if ($3 > 10) print $3}' file.txt`, the result is the same, values lower than 10 are not filtered out, e.g.: `17.9344; 3.68367; 2.37445; 163.557; 172.775`. Might that have something to do with uneven length of the fractional parts in my values?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It fails if the file has CRLF line terminators. Remove the `\r` first:

```
$ file foo
foo: ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators
$ mawk 'sub(/\r/,"") && ($3 > 10)'  foo
9_6_F-repl      24834   38.8699
9_6_F   56523   17.9344
9_annua_M-merg  122663  163.557
9_huetii_F-merg 208077  172.775
```

Alternatively you could use `dos2unix` or such.

**EDIT2**: If you are using locale that has comma as decimal separator, it affects float comparisons in mawk.

In this case you can either:

1) set locale to

```
LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
```

or

2) change decimal separators to commas and pipe it to mawk:

```
mawk '$3 > 10' <(cat file.txt | sed -e "s/\./,/")
```

Comment: `dos2unix foo && mawk '$3 > 10' foo` still gives the same result. Also `mawk 'sub(/\r/,"")'` gives no result whatsoever (output is empty). The result of `file foo` is `foo: ASCII text`

Comment: Which locale are you on (type `locale`) ? Maybe your locale uses another decimal separator, comma for example.

Comment: You are right! It's locale problem. It works perfectly after I change periods to commas: `mawk '$3 > 10' <(cat out.idepth | sed -e "s/\./,/")`. Good to remember that mawk uses locale info while awk does not.

Comment: I tried to change my locale to something with comma as separator but still couldn't reproduce. Which locale are you using?

Comment: It's `"pl_PL.UTF-8"`.

Comment: Setting locale to `LANG="en_US.UTF-8"` solves the problem and `mawk '$3 > 10' foo` works just like it should.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to set locale, but need to account for strange or errorneous input :

If the input has a dot, or any character than has a byte ordinance higher than ASCII "1" (which is a LOT of stuff) :

```
9_6_F-repl      24834   9.
9_6_F   56523   9.
9_annua_M-merg  122663  9.
9_huetii_F-merg 208077  9.
9_annua_M-merg  122663  :5.333
```

this would completely fail to produce the correct result, since `$3` is being compared as a string, where an ASCII "9" is larger than ASCII "1" :

```
mawk2 'sub("\r*",_)*(10<$3)'

9_6_F-repl      24834   9.
9_6_F   56523   9.
9_annua_M-merg  122663  9.
9_huetii_F-merg 208077  9.
9_annua_M-merg  122663  9.
9_annua_M-merg  122663  :5.333
```

To rectify it, simply add `+` next to `$3` :

```
mawk 'sub("\r*",_)*(10<+$3)'
```

If you don't care much for archaic `gawk -P/-c/-t` modes then it's even simpler :

```
mawk '10<+$3' RS='\r?\n'
```

Let `ORS` take care of the `\r`::**CR** on your behalf. By placing the `?` at the RS regex, you can skip all the steps about using `iconv` or `dos2unix` or changing `locale` settings ::

- `RS`—-->`ORS` would seamlessly handle it

This way the original input file remains intact, in case you need those CRs later for some reason.